# Convert Dash-Separated String to camelCase via C#

Tags: c#, regex, string-conversion

I have a large XML file that contain tag names that implement the dash-separated naming convention. How can I use C# to convert the tag names to the camel case naming convention?

The rules are:
1. Convert all characters to lower case
2. Capitalize the first character *after* each dash
3. Remove all dashes

**Example**
**Before Conversion**

```
<foo-bar>
 <a-b-c></a-b-c>
</foo-bar>
```

**After Conversion**

```
<fooBar>
 <aBC></aBC>
</fooBar>
```

Here's a code example that works, but it's slow to process - I'm thinking that there is a better way to accomplish my goal.

```
string ConvertDashToCamelCase(string input)
{
    input = input.ToLower();
    char[] ca = input.ToCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < ca.Length; i++)
    {
        if(ca[i] == '-')
        {
            string t = ca[i + 1].ToString().toUpper();
            sb.Append(t);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(ca[i].ToString());
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Provide some code so we can help you... we won't do the work for you.

Comment: Okay - Code example added to my OP. As you can see, I brute-forced my way through the characters. This method works, but it is very slow. I'm hoping to find a solution that is cleaner and quicker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186641/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17186641/how-do-i-make-letters-to-uppercase-after-each-of-a-set-of-specific-characters) with the exception of removing the special characters after capitalizing the letters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason your original code was slow is because you're calling `ToString` all over the place unnecessarily. There's no need for that. There's also no need for the intermediate array of `char`. The following should be much faster, and faster than the version that uses `String.Split`, too.

```
string ConvertDashToCamelCase(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool caseFlag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
    {
        char c = input[i];
        if (c == '-')
        {
            caseFlag = true;
        }
        else if (caseFlag)
        {
            sb.Append(char.ToUpper(c));
            caseFlag = false;
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(char.ToLower(c));
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

I'm not going to claim that the above is the fastest possible. In fact, there are several obvious optimizations that could save some time. But the above is clean and clear: easy to understand.

The key is the `caseFlag`, which you use to indicate that the next character copied should be set to upper case. Also note that I don't automatically convert the entire string to lower case. There's no reason to, since you'll be looking at every character anyway and can do the appropriate conversion at that time.

The idea here is that the code doesn't do any more work than it absolutely has to.

Comment: It should be noted that this method can also do conversions to `PascalCase` simply by initializing `caseFlag` to `true` at the start.

Answer (score 5):

For completeness, here's also a regular expression one-liner (inspred by [this JavaScript answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60738940/87698)):

```
string ConvertDashToCamelCase(string input) =>
    Regex.Replace(input, "-.", m => m.Value.ToUpper().Substring(1));
```

It replaces all occurrences of `-x` with `x` converted to upper case.

---

Special cases:

- If you want lower-case all other characters, replace `input` with `input.ToLower()` inside the expression:

  ```
    string ConvertDashToCamelCase(string input) =>
        Regex.Replace(input.ToLower(), "-.", m => m.Value.ToUpper().Substring(1));
  ```
- If you want to support multiple dashes between words (`dash--case`) and have all of the dashes removed (`dashCase`), replace `-` with `-+` in the regular expression (to greedily match all sequences of dashes) and keep only the final character:

  ```
    string ConvertDashToCamelCase(string input) =>
        Regex.Replace(input, "-+.", m => m.Value.ToUpper().Substring(m.Value.Length - 1));
  ```
- If you want to support multiple dashes between words (`dash--case`) and remove only the final one (`dash-Case`), change the regular expression to match only a dash followed by a non-dash (rather than a dash followed by any character):

  ```
    string ConvertDashToCamelCase(string input) =>
        Regex.Replace(input, "-[^-]", m => m.Value.ToUpper().Substring(1));
  ```

Comment: Just a clarification: for the lowercase alternative, the `input.ToLower()` would be the first parameter for `Replace` (by *expression* somebody could understand the Linq evaluator).

Comment: @Andrew: Good point, I've added an explicit example to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
string ConvertDashToCamelCase(string input)
{
    string[] words = input.Split('-');

    words = words.Select(element => wordToCamelCase(element));

    return string.Join("", words);
}

string wordToCamelCase(string input)
{
    return input.First().ToString().ToUpper() + input.Substring(1).ToLower();
}
```

Comment: I don't have a machine to try this code on, but will this work with a tag like `<foo-bar>tag-content</foo-bar>`? That is, what if the tag holds a value which is itself hyphenated?

Comment: @s.m.: This code and the OP's code assume you want to do the conversion for the entire string. If you want to camel-case the tag but not the content, you have to separate them yourself.

Comment: @JimMischel OP explicitly wrote "How can I use C# to convert the **tag names** to the camel case naming convention?". That's why I felt like warning against a possible mangling of the XML content, OP might not have thought of that. In other words, I was offering an extra pair of eyes.

Comment: @s.m. The XML file that I'm parsing happens to not have any content. So, Jim's solution is great. However, you are correct - Jim's solution as it sits will camelCase all tags and content.

Comment: @s.m. - I added and answer that is an updated version of Jim Mischel's code that will only camelCase the XML tag names (not the content).

Comment: @Jed good. The only other thing I can think of right now that might require further refining is `CDATA` sections. But that would open a whole other can of worms, because they are likely to span multiple lines, so a complete change of approach would be in order.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an updated version of @Jim Mischel's answer that will ignore the content - i.e. it will only camelCase tag names.

```
string ConvertDashToCamelCase(string input)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    bool caseFlag = false;
    bool tagFlag = false; 
    for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    {   
        char c = input[i];
        if(tagFlag)
        {
            if (c == '-')
            {
                caseFlag = true;
            }
            else if (caseFlag)
            {
                sb.Append(char.ToUpper(c));
                caseFlag = false;
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(char.ToLower(c));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Append(c);
        }

        // Reset tag flag if necessary
        if(c == '>' || c == '<')
        {
            tagFlag = (c == '<');
        }

    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I think you'll need to reset the `caseFlag` when you enter a tag. Otherwise something like `<foo->content</foo-><bar>xxx</bar>` will result in `<foo>content</foo><Bar>xxx</bar>` (i.e. the `bar` tag will be capitalized). My function suffers from the same problem because my understanding of your requirements is that you were passing a tag name to the function, not a whole line of XML text.

Comment: @JimMischel - It turns out that after the caseFlag is set to true, there will eventually be a char that is a closing tag (>). And when the char is a closing tag, the "else if (caseFlag)" condition is met. Which means that the caseFlag will always be reset to false. In other words, your code works fine as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class MyString
{
  public static string ToCamelCase(string str)
  {
    char[] s = str.ToCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
      if (s[i] == '-' || s[i] == '_')
        sb.Append(Char.ToUpper(s[++i]));
      else
        sb.Append(s[i]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: code only answers are discouraged, you should explain the code in your answer so users can understand what you are doing and why