# Convert kebab-case to camelCase with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, camelcasing, kebab-case

Say I have a function that transforms `kebab-case` to `camelCase`:

```
camelize("my-kebab-string") === 'myKebabString';
```

I'm almost there, but my code outputs the first letter with uppercase too:

```
function camelize(str){
  let arr = str.split('-');
  let capital = arr.map(item=> item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1).toLowerCase());
  let capitalString = capital.join("");

  console.log(capitalString);
}
    
camelize("my-kebab-string");
```

Comment: arr.map((item, index)) => if (index > 0) { ... } else { ... })

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can also try regex.

```
camelize = s => s.replace(/-./g, x=>x[1].toUpperCase())
```

```js
const camelize = s => s.replace(/-./g, x=>x[1].toUpperCase())
const words = ["stack-overflow","camel-case","alllowercase","allcapitalletters","custom-xml-parser","api-finder","json-response-data","person20-address","user-api20-endpoint"];
console.log(words.map(camelize));
```

Looks only for hyphen followed by any character, and capitalises it and replaces the hyphen+character with the capitalised character.

Comment: Genius, but I would go with `x=>x[1].toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 14):

To keep your existing code, I've just added a check on the index that will return `item` instead of the transformed item if item is 0 (falsy), since the problem is just that you are upper-casing the first item as well, while you shouldn't.

In a nutshell, the inline expression becomes: `(item, index) => index ? item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1).toLowerCase() : item`, because:

- If index is not falsy (so, if index is > 0 in your context), the capitalized string is returned.
- Otherwise, the current item is returned.

Of course, this could be cleaner and likely single line, but I wanted to stay as close as possible to your code so that you could understand what was wrong:

```js
function camelize(str){
  let arr = str.split('-');
  let capital = arr.map((item, index) => index ? item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1).toLowerCase() : item.toLowerCase());
  // ^-- change here.
  let capitalString = capital.join("");

  console.log(capitalString);
}

camelize("my-kebab-string");
```

As a side note, you could've found a potential cleaner answer here: [Converting any string into camel case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970525/converting-any-string-into-camel-case)

Comment: I knew that I can use the index attribute for this case, but don't wonder how currently. Thank You very much!

Comment: @RobertHovhannisyan well, the index is just one of the possible solutions out there. For performance reasons, you may want to check the linked topic, this can easily be accomplished with a single regex instead of mapping :).

Answer (score 5):

For [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) users:

```
_.camelCase('my-kebab-string') => 'myKebabString'
```

Answer (score 2):

The first method is to just transform to lower case the first entry of your `capital` array, like this:

```
capital[0] = capital[0].toLowerCase();
```

Another method, which I think to be more efficient, is to pass another parameter to the `map` callback, which is the `index`. Take a look at this for further reading:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

So you transform to upper case only `if (index > 0)`.
Like this:

```
let capital = arr.map((item, index) => index ? item.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.slice(1).toLowerCase() : item);
```

Answer (score 0):

so I tried both array-string and regex but regex is slower !

```js
const string = " background-color: red; \n color: red;\n z-index: 10"

// regex
console.time("regex")
let property = string
const camelProp = property.replace(/(-[a-z])/, (g) => {
  return g.replace("-", "").toUpperCase()
})
console.timeEnd("regex")

// custom
console.time("custom")
const str = string
let strNew = str
  .split("-")
  .map((e) => {
    return e[0].toUpperCase() + e.slice(1)
  })
  .join("")

console.timeEnd("custom")

console.log(camelProp)
console.log(strNew)
```